# colored toc and shorttoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, color, shorttoc

I want to have colored part and chapter names in my shorttoc *and* my toc. So I worked out how to get the shorttoc colored, but I do not know how to get the toc also colored the same way? If I add the commands twice (between `\makelatter` and `\makeatother`) it does not work. So how can I get both colored the same way?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\color{headercolor}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\titleformat{\section}
{\color{headercolor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{headercolor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\color{headercolor}\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\color{headercolor}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 

\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.6941,0.6745,0.4863}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\makeatletter
\let\stdl@part\l@part
\renewcommand*{\l@part}[2]{%
  \stdl@part{\textcolor{headercolor}{#1}}{\textcolor{headercolor}{#2}}}
\let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \stdl@chapter{\textcolor{headercolor}{#1}}{\textcolor{headercolor}{#2}}}

\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\shorttableofcontents{Inhalts\"ubersicht}{1}
\bookmark[page=15,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},color=red]{Inhalts\"ubersicht}
\bookmark[page=17,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},color=red]{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\mainmatter

\part{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test1}
\section{test2}
and so on....
and so on.....
\end{document}
```

Now the shorttoc is colored bot not the toc, but I want both colored.

Comment: This really isn't a MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: any hints though? By the way, what is not working?

Comment: @Daniel E. Shub maybe you have a solution for me?

Comment: @Gerondus I have edited your MWE, namely made it shorter, such that problem you have is still visible.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, you're modifying `\l@part` and `\l@chapter` to add color to the respective ToC entries. But you also load the `tocstyle` package and choose the `allwithdot` style, which means that your former modifications won't affect the normal ToC, only the one created by `shorttoc` (which isn't controlled by `tocstyle`). Result: The short ToC is colored, but missing dots for parts/chapter entries, while the normal ToC features the dots, but is missing the color. One way to achieve a consistent ToC layout is to simply remove the lines

```
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
```

from your preamble. The other way (if you want color *and* dots for part/chapter entries) is to get rid of `shorttoc` and to use `toctsyle`'s `\showtoc` command to produce a partial ToC (see p. 10 of the manual for details).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\color{headercolor}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\color{headercolor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\color{headercolor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.6941,0.6745,0.4863}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\settocstylefeature[-1]{entryhook}{\color{headercolor}\bfseries\large}
\settocstylefeature[0]{entryhook}{\color{headercolor}\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{savedtocdepth}
\setcounter{savedtocdepth}{\value{tocdepth}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\chapter*{Inhalts\"ubersicht}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Inhalts\"ubersicht}}{\MakeUppercase{Inhalts\"ubersicht}}
\showtoc{toc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{savedtocdepth}}

\tableofcontents

\part{test}

\chapter{test}

\section{test1}

\subsection{test11}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]